# Return items within Date Range

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, spfx-webparts

My array:

```
 urlArray =  dataArray.map(function(item){
              return {
               Id:                               item.Id,
               Title:                            item.Title, 
               StartDate:                        new Date(item.Start_x0020_Date).toLocaleDateString("en-GB"),                       
               EndDate:                          new Date(item.End_x0020_Date).toLocaleDateString("en-GB"),                                 
                };   
          });

var nextYear   = '01/01/2019';
```

How can I return return all items that have a start date that begins in this year (2018)? This is the same as excluding all items which have a start date > next year (i.e. 2019).

urlArray returns each date format as so: 
`1/1/1970` 
whereas in browser tools the API returns a date format of:

```
"2018-12-26T08:00:00Z"
```

I have tried returning all items with a filter that have a start date less than next year but still not working. My attempt is below:

```
let filteredAZLista = urlArray.filter(c =>  c.StartDate < nextYear);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do your comparisons by using `Date` objects, not strings, and you could do your filter before you do your string conversions in your `map` function, that way you are mapping over already filtered data.

So something like this:

```
var nextYear = new Date('01/01/2019');

var filteredData = dataArray.filter(item => new Date(item.Start_x0020_Date) < nextYear);

urlArray =  filteredData.map(function(item){
    return {
     Id:                               item.Id,
     Title:                            item.Title, 
     StartDate:                        new Date(item.Start_x0020_Date).toLocaleDateString("en-GB"),                       
     EndDate:                          new Date(item.End_x0020_Date).toLocaleDateString("en-GB"),                                 
      };   
});
```